# Filtering my table in react does not work

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a filter functionality in a component. The filtered rows depend upon the state object and the initial list is being passed through the 'props'. I initialize the state in componentWillMount but the list in props is always empty, however when I do a console.log in the render() method the values are there. What am I doing wrong ?

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ 
      data: this.props.possibleValues,
      filteredValues: this.props.possibleValues
    });
    console.log(this.props.possibleValues) //empty
    console.log(this.state.filteredValues) //empty
  }
```

Comment: Three quick things. 1. Can you post a minimal example to jsbin that we can play with? 2. If the data comes in via props, why are you assigning it to state? 3. If you state is based on props and is synchronous, initializing it belongs in the constructor rather than `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Can you post your example without it, it is hard to help.  I also think that if you are trying to use state this should be done in the constructor.

Comment: Creating a minimal example looks difficult as I am deep into the component hierarchy. I am loading the data asynchronously, can that be the problem ? If so, where should I be initializing the state ?

Comment: @Akhil          I posted an example below based on you trying to pass the props to the component and have it use the state to store the filteredValues.   You can update the render, I just put in another simple component which could consume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say based on your description but if you are trying to pass the `initial value` via `props` and then have the values held within your `state` here is an example.  The values for your `filtered values` are updated each time your onChange would be called in your render and stored within `selected`.

This will work for ansychronous calls, in your render you wait until the state is set on the parent object before allowing the child component to be rendered.

```
someAsyncSetup() {
... doing something   
        this.setState({
            possibleValues : possibleValues 
        });
}
```

Inside the componentDidMount()  you set your state for possible values which is ansynchronous.  Once you get your values call setState().  Then the render will wait until it is completed before creating the child component

```
{this.state.possibleValues != null &&...
    <ExampleChild...
```

## Example of parent comp

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {possibleValues: null};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.someAsyncSetup = this.someAsyncSetup.bind(this);
}

onChange(selected) {
    this.props.onChange({ selected });  // you may need to call your parent props again
}

someAsyncSetup() {
... doing something   
            this.setState({
                possibleValues : possibleValues 
            });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.someAsyncSetup(); // inside here you set your state for possible values.  Then the render will wait until it is completed before creating the child component
}

 {this.state.possibleValues != null &&
                <ExampleChild
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    possibleValues={this.state.possibleValues}
            }
```

## Example of child comp

```
    class ExampleChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selected: this.props.filteredValues };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    // onChange we want to set the list of selected values
    onChange(selected) {
        this.setState({ selected });
        // call the parent component's onChange so that we set the values
        // within the parents component state
        this.props.onChange(selected);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <someComp
            options={this.props.possibleValues}
            selected={this.state.selected}
            defaultValue={this.props.filteredValues}
            onChange={this.onChange} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If we want to stet the values in parent component's state then why do we need a state in child component ? Also, I am loading the data asynchronously and when I try to initialize in constructor , props is empty.

Comment: @Akhil         I went through this before and had to get help.  To allow you to get the state into the parent you need to pass it via a function from the parent.  You can see the this.props.onChange(selected) call in the onChange.  This will pass the selected details to the parent component.  This parent component then needs to use that to set its state.  That is how you can pass the details back to the parent.

You need to make sure to wait before rendering your component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would try this.

Comment: @Akhil         Did that work for you?  If so can you please mark the answer correct.  Thank you